# I want to read from external file flutter and store it in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

Am new in flutter, I am developing a dictionary of my mother language, I have a file which each line contains a word and meaning separated by `@` example `word@meaning`, I am having difficulty in reading from the file and storing it in List, for example

this is the list of words and meanings in separated file, so instead of having this lists, I want to read from my file

```
 List<String> worda = [
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
];

List<String> meaninga = [
  "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
   "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
   "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
   "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
];
```

this is the complete code of a class that manipulate my two list

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'fileUtility.dart';
class WordList {
  final String word;
  final String meaning;
  const WordList({required this.word, required this.meaning});
}

final dictionary = List<WordList>.generate(
  worda.length, (index) => WordList(word: worda[index], meaning: meaninga[index]),
);

List<String> worda = [
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
  "àbàdâ",
  "ágábà",
  "bàba",
  "badà",
  "céndzũ̀",
];

List<String> meaninga = [
  "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
   "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
   "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
   "Eternal, everlasting,forever ",
  "Salutation for the rank Tswanyã",
  "River bank eroded by water that may fall at any time",
  "To stalk; to walk slowly; to move stealthily;",
  "Unripe nut of the oil palm",
];
```

this is my file utility code

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class FileUtility {
  static Future<String> get getFilePath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  static Future<File> get getFile async {
    final path = await getFilePath;
    return File("$path/nupe.txt");
  }

  static Future<File> saveFile(String data) async {
    final file = await getFile;
    return file.writeAsString(data, mode: FileMode.append);
  }

  static Future<List> readFile() async{
    try {
      final file = await getFile;
      final contents = await file.readAsLines();
      return contents;
    } catch(e){
      return [];
    }
  }  
}
```

this is my flutter code for design and views

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'JSON.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  List<WordList> words = dictionary;
  List<String> listWords = worda;
  List<String> listMeanings = meaninga;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(           
           title: Text('Nupe / English Dictionary'),
           elevation: 0.0,
         ),
         body: Container(
           child: Column(
             children: [
               Container(
                 color: Colors.blue,
                 padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
                 child: TextField(
                   controller: controller,
                  scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left:15),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Enter Nupe/English Word...',
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)                   
                  ),
                  onChanged: search,
                ),
               ),
               Container(                 
                 child: Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: words.length,                  
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext contex, int index){
                      final word = words[index];
                      final listWord = listWords[index];
                      final listMeaning = listMeanings[index];
                      return ListTile(
                      tileColor: Colors.white,
                      onTap: null,
                      title: Text(word.word,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(word.meaning,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
         ),
      );
  }
  void search(String value) {
    final suggestions = dictionary.where((word) {
      final wordd = word.word.toLowerCase();
      final input = value.toLowerCase();
      return wordd.contains(input);
    }).toList();
    setState(() => words = suggestions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you are learning flutter!

If you need to use files in flutter, and you want those to be shipped with your app, you'll need to use assets:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

If you want the user to specify a file, i.e. showing a file selection dialog you'll need something like:
https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

after having loaded that file, you'll only have to split by newlines ('\n') and than your entries are word@meaning which you than could split again on the @ sign.

Seeing your approach, I suggest you to consider using JSON for having formatted data in text-form :) There is a lot of good tools that make things way easier.